# how to optimize my code in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery, it repeats 5 times for 5 buttons. 
I'm not good in Jquery, so I want to ask how can I optimize my code in 1 function ? Thanks

```
$(function() {
    $("#frmEdit\\:idBtn1").datetimepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "../../jquery/images/calendarIcon.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        constrainInput: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy    ',
        addSliderAccess: true,
        sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
    });
});
$(function() {
    $("#frmEdit\\:idBtn2").datetimepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "../../jquery/images/calendarIcon.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        constrainInput: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy    ',
        addSliderAccess: true,
        sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
    });
});
..........
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use multiple selectors.  http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```
$("#frmEdit\\:idBtn1, #frmEdit\\:idBtn2")
```

If you have more than a few things to select, I would suggest setting a class, and use a class selector instead.

Comment: Thanks you all of you so much

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a function

```
function createDatePicker(id) {
    $("#frmEdit\\:" + id).datetimepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "../../jquery/images/calendarIcon.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        constrainInput: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy    ',
        addSliderAccess: true,
        sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
    });
};
```

Usage

```
createDatePicker('idBtn1');
```